# Adding infos to edges/vertices by name

Tags: python, igraph

I try to add new attribute values to certain vertices and edges, from which I only have the names.

```
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(["1","2","3"])
g.add_edges([("1","2"),("2","3")])
```

What is the best way to add attributes to certain vertices and edges?

I found the following but this seems unnecessary verbose:

```
g.vs.find(name="1")["attribute"] = "value"
g.get_eid(g.vs.find(name="1").index, g.vs.find(name="2").index)
```

What you can't do is the following, which I tried

```
g.vs["1"] # -> would return the attribute list if there would be an attribute "1"
g.get_eid("1","2") # needs integers...
```

Is there a better way to refer to edges and vertices by names?

[Background: I first tried to build my graph sequentially (where I know each vertex id for each name) but that didn't scale (add_edge seem to have O(n²) behavior). But now I don't know the vertex ids and can't assign edge attributes. I don't really want to construct each attribute list beforehand as my current add_edges() call is a mess of itertools functionality]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the easiest is simple construct a reverse dictionary to link from names to vertices (or edges):

```
n2id = dict(zip(graph.vs["name"],[v.index for v in graph.vs]))
name = "J. Smith" # name of the vertices you are interested in
neighbors = graph.neighborhood(n2id[name], order=1)
```